# Date Picker not populating after override Expand method in Extjs

Tags: extjs, datepicker

I wanted to set different date in Extjs date picker by replacing default date of date picker that comes system date.
for that I override Date field - below is my code -

```
Ext.override(Ext.form.field.Date, {
               expand: function() {
               var value = this.getValue();
               var customDate = '07/08/2013';
               var myDate = new Date(customDate );
               this.getPicker().setValue(Ext.isDate(value) ? value : myDate);
          }
});
```

Now I was expecting myDate as default in picker.
But picker is not populating when I click on picker to select date.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue myself. Here is the code to do that. Hopefully it will help someone and will save precious time.

```
Ext.override(Ext.form.field.Date, {
  expand: function() {
         var myDate = new Date('07/08/2017');
         var value = this.getValue();
         this.getPicker().setValue(Ext.isDate(value) ? value : myDate);
         var me = this,  bodyEl, picker, collapseIf;
         if (me.rendered && !me.isExpanded && !me.isDestroyed) {
                  bodyEl = me.bodyEl;
                  picker = me.getPicker();
                  collapseIf = me.collapseIf;
                  me.isExpanded = true;
                  me.alignPicker();
                  bodyEl.addCls(me.openCls);
                  me.mon(Ext.getDoc(), {
                  mousewheel: collapseIf,
                  mousedown: collapseIf,
                  scope: me
        }); Ext.EventManager.onWindowResize(me.alignPicker, me);
               me.fireEvent('expand', me);
     }
  }
});
```